# Django Customize many to many query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have extended Django's default User class by adding a *ManyToManyField* to another table called `Algorithm`. The new User class is:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    algorithms = ManyToManyField(Algorithm, blank=True, default=None, related_name="users")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username})
```

I want to specify if the user `is_superuser` or `is_staff` then `User.algorithms.all()` will get all algorithms. Otherwise, get only the records in the pivot table `User_user_models`. How can this be achieved? I tried to add a property method that check if superuser/staff then return all otherwise return super but it didn't work.

*P.S: during creating/editing the user, if user is set to superuser or staff, then there is no need to choose algorithms.*

Comment: I would make a custom relation manager here. Typically it is not a good idea to override default Django logic.

Comment: I assume this is not supposed to be a model field then. It's just a method. Your actual usr-alg matches are stored in non-related to User model table `User_user_models` and for particular users you don't need any matches at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you have an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would just overwrite the `save()` method:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    algorithms = ManyToManyField(Algorithm, blank=True, default=None, related_name="users")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username})

    def save(self, **kwargs):

         if self.is_superuser or self.is_staff:
             self.algorithms = Algorithm.objects.all()

         else:
             # Get your users from your pivot table

         super().save()
```